# making the [...] clickable

Tags: excerpt

I have created a child theme for twenty twelve.

In this child theme I have added a `content.php` file and have copied and pasted the entire parent `content.php` and pasted it in to the child theme version.

I have changed this line.

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
```

with this one

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_archive() || is_author() || is_tag() || is_home() ) : // Only display Excerpts  ?>
```

This reduces the post on my home page and added `[..]` to the end of it which is what I wanted it to do.

What I want now is for the `[..]` to be click able. So that it goes to the full post. Just like it does when you click the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following piece of code just below `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` inside the loop as explained in the codex [Excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt)

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More...</a>
```